# How to List All Custom Post Types Names (Not Posts)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

Having Some Custom Post Types Like `"Projects", "Products"` and `"Events"` I need to list them in a page. Please be advis that I do not want to list any POST here! instead I just want query the name of all Custom post type and Link them into `archive-projects.php`, `archive-products.php` and `archive-events.php` for each of them. Can you please let me know how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get all custom post types:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array ( '_builtin' => FALSE ), 'objects' );
```

Sort them by their name:

```
uasort( $post_types, 'sort_cpts_by_label' );

/**
 * Sort post types by their display label.
 *
 * @param object $cpt1
 * @param object $cpt2
 * @return int
 */
function sort_cpts_by_label( $cpt1, $cpt2 ) {

    return strcasecmp(
        $cpt1->labels->name,
        $cpt2->labels->name
    );
}
```

Link the post type names to their archives if archives are actually available:

```
foreach ( $post_types as $post_type => $properties ) {
    if ( $properties->has_archive ) {
        printf(
            '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br>',
            get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ),
            $properties->labels->name
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Exactly my solution as well :-) +1

Comment: @PieterGoosen Don’t tell me that you had included the sorting!

Comment: That I did not include. Like that idea of sorting them. To be honest, I would have never thought of that. :-)

Comment: @toscho Thanks you, just about sorting part cant' we just use the query sorting parameter here?

Comment: Like `'orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');` ?

Comment: @MonaCoder The sorting is not for any queries, it just orders the names by their display name. This is important when the post type labels are localized.

Comment: what I was thinking was passing  `'orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC');` in `get_post_types()` function. so you think this is not doable?

Comment: @MonaCoder No, that’s not a valid parameter for `get_post_types()`.